# hide navigationview headerlayout imageview dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-navigationview

> I am implementing navigation view and its has header view how to hide the image view dynamically
>
> Below is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

> drawer_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_logo_icon"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/logo_white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/drawer_header_text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

> To get the menu item i can use navigationview.getmenuID(). But how to hide the header layout image programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id to the root layout of your `drawer_header.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    .............
```

Then simply hide it by getting its reference in code.

```
RelativeLayout drawerHeaderLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_header_layout);
drawerHeaderLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

That will hide your Navigation View header. (Works for me)

EDIT: (Better way)

Another way to remove the header completely is [removeHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#removeHeaderView(android.view.View))

```
 NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
 view.removeHeaderView(drawerHeaderLayout);
```